# Nested forms with join table attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a new Match form:
EDIT:

```
= form_for(@match) do |f|
  = f.label :match_date
  = f.date_select :match_date, :order => [:day, :month, :year]
  = f.label :player_ids, 'Select players'
  = f.collection_select :player_ids, @players, :id, :lastname, {}, { multiple: true }

  = f.fields_for :match_edits do |ff|
    = ff.label :result
    = ff.number_field :result, in: 0..10
  %div
    = f.button :submit
```

When I choose two players I want set for each one match result like this:

> id: 1, match_id: 1, player_id: 1, result: 4
>
> id: 2, match_id: 1, player_id: 2, result: 10

I'm new in rails and I don't know how to fix that

MatchController

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @matches = Match.all
  end

  def show
    @match = Match.find(params[:id])
    @results = @match.match_edits
  end

  def new
    @match = Match.new
    @players = Player.all
    2.times {@match.match_edits.build}
  end

  def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @match.save
        format.html { redirect_to @match, notice: 'Match was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @match }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def match_params
    params[:match].permit :match_date, player_ids: [], :match_edits_attributes => [:id, :result]
  end

end
```

MatchEdit model

```
class MatchEdit < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :match
    belongs_to :player

end
```

Match model

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :match_edits
    has_many :players, through: :match_edits
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :match_edits, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs['result'].blank? }

end
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150629144534) do

  create_table "match_edits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "match_id"
    t.integer  "player_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "result"
  end

  add_index "match_edits", ["match_id"], name: "index_match_edits_on_match_id"
  add_index "match_edits", ["player_id"], name: "index_match_edits_on_player_id"

  create_table "matches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "match_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: Post your model & controller `new` action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Form should look like this:

```
= form_for(@match) do |f|
  = f.label :match_date
  = f.date_select :match_date, :order => [:day, :month, :year]

  = f.fields_for :match_edits do |ff|
    = ff.label :player_id, 'Select player'
    = ff.collection_select :player_id, @players, :id, :lastname, {}, { multiple: false }
    = ff.label :result
    = ff.number_field :result, in: 0..10
  %div
    = f.button :submit
```

and in matches_controller:

```
 def match_params
    params[:match].permit :match_date, :match_edits_attributes => [:id, :result, :player_id]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your form to remove redundant code i.e.:

`= ff.number_field :result, in: 0..10`

Your form will look like:

```
= form_for(@match) do |f|
  = f.label :match_date
  = f.date_select :match_date, :order => [:day, :month, :year]
  = f.label :player_ids, 'Select players'
  = f.collection_select :player_ids, @players, :id, :lastname, {}, { multiple: true }

  = f.fields_for :match_edits do |ff|
    = ff.label :result
    = ff.number_field :result, in: 0..10
  %div
    = f.button :submit
```

Your controller's `new` method is responsible to to provide multiple fields for `result`:

```
class MatchsController << ApplicationContoller
  ...

  def new
    ...
    2.times { @match.match_edits.build }
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

Your model should allow to accept nested attributes as following:

```
class Match
  ...

  has_many :match_edits
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :match_edits, allow_destroy: true,
                                 reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs['result'].blank? }

  ...
end

class MatchEdit
  ...

  belongs_to :match

  ...
end
```

Comment: It's create 4 records to MatchEdit table 
`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MatchEdit id: 1, match_id: 1, player_id: 1, created_at: "2015-07-05 17:00:24", updated_at: "2015-07-05 17:00:24", result: nil>, #<MatchEdit id: 2, match_id: 1, player_id: 2, created_at: "2015-07-05 17:00:24", updated_at: "2015-07-05 17:00:24", result: nil>, #<MatchEdit id: 3, match_id: 1, player_id: nil, created_at: "2015-07-05 17:00:24", updated_at: "2015-07-05 17:00:24", result: 10>, #<MatchEdit id: 4, match_id: 1, player_id: nil, created_at: "2015-07-05 17:00:24", updated_at: "2015-07-05 17:00:24", result: 6>]>`

Comment: Show me your updated `form`. Make sure you don't have `ff.number_field :result, in: 0..10` twice.

Comment: @wert I can see a discrepancy here: In your form, you have specified `:result` attribute for `match_edits`, however, you don't have `result` column in your table.

Comment: `result` column is in match_edits table. I add my schema.rb.

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :match_edits, allow_destroy: true,
                                 reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs['result'].blank? }`

Comment: Still makes 4 records like in first comment.

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :match_edits, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs['result'].blank? || attrs['result'].nil? }` this? If still facing same issue, post your params that are coming to your action